# SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Access - Allow zero length issue

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013, sql-server-migration-assi

My Access 2013 database tables have columns of type "Long Text" that have the Required property set to 'No' and the 'Allow zero length' property set to 'Yes'.
Why then the [SSMA for Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313041(v=sql.110).aspx) is creating a check constraint on these columns as:

```
Create table table1(c1 nvarchar(max),  constraint c_ssma_disallow_zero_length  check(len(c1) >0))
```

The above check constraint forces the SQL Server nvarchar column to have a non-zero length.